# change the text of toggle button in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on audio player in angularjs. I have customized the player according to the requirements but stuck with the mute button. In the demo [link for demo](http://perminder-klair.github.io/angular-soundmanager2/example.html)

you will see a mute toggle button whose value is changing from true to false and vice versa when in toggles. I want to change the value from mute to muted and then again to mute. I have to make changes in main js file but getting confused.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something  ?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: <button  mute-music > {{ mute?"muted":"mute" }}</button> It worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<button>{isMuted ? "Muted" : "Mute"}</button>
```

`isMuted` is your boolean flag which indicates if its muted or not.